# Найти дубли записей в базе

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. 40 тыс. записей. Очень много записей с одинаковыми заголовками (точь  в точь).
Задача: поиск дублей и вывод их с идентификатором .

Пробую

```
    $array=array();
    $db_query="select  id_advert, name_adv from ".DB_PREF."advert ";
    list($kol,$data)=obr_db_query_select_assoc($db_query);//ассоциативный массив

    foreach($data as $one){
       $array[]=$one['name_adv'];
    }

    $array=array_count_values($array);
```

на выходе я получаю  значение => кол-во повторов

Как я полагаю, двигаюсь я не совсем в нужную сторону, поэтому хочу узнать вашего совета. В данном случае как мне еще заносить id_advert в результат повторов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name_adv, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_advert) identifiers_list
FROM advert 
GROUP BY name_adv
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_advert) > 1
```

Если же пары (name_adv, id_advert) гарантированно уникальны - DISTINCT-ы можно убрать.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло